# install package login with linkedin

Tags: php, laravel-5, linkedin-api

I'm trying to install oauth-5-laravel package for my laravel 5 project, but I'm getting the error when I'm trying to run the command composer update in ubuntu terminal.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.4.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.4.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.3.4 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.3.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.3.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.3.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.3.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.2.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.2.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.2.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.1.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.0.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.0.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - fairholm/elasticquent v1.0.0 requires elasticsearch/elasticsearch ~1.0 -> satisfiable by elasticsearch/elasticsearch[v1.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.2.1, v1.2.2, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2, v1.3.3, v1.3.4, v1.4.0, v1.4.1].
    - Installation request for fairholm/elasticquent 1.0.* -> satisfiable by fairholm/elasticquent[v1.0.0].
```

so how can I resolve this problem? thanks in advance.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

Answer (score 0):

> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

In fact, it tells you to install **Curl** on your system...

So, If you're beginner in english and with ubuntu, you can run a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`  + `Enter` to install Curl on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Either you haven't installed or enabled the `curl` php extension.

1. Check if it is indeed installed

In your terminal run the following command to see where the `.ini` file is located

```
php -i | grep ini
```

Should output something like this

```
Loaded Configuration File => /path/to/php.ini
```

Now check the `php.ini` to see if you do have the extension enabled or not

```
grep curl /the/above/path/to/php.ini
```

If it's disabled you should see it commented, as follows

```
#extension=curl.so
```

Simply uncomment, and have fun

If it's not there, proceed to

2. Install the `php-curl` extension, by running the below in your terminal

   apt-get install php5-curl

Check if it has been enabled

```
php -m | grep curl
```

If all went well, it should output

```
curl
```